# Hive: Invalid Column Reference

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

In Hive, I've got four tables:

- temp_basic_info (ID, MSISDN, GENDER, AGE, DAY, MONTH, YEAR, RELATIONSHIPSTATUS)
- temp_education (ID, EDUCATION)
- likes_and_music (ID, NAME, PAGE)
- temp_output (ID, MSISDN, GENDER, AGE, DAY, MONTH, YEAR, RELATIONSHIPSTATUS, EDUCATION, LIKES_AND_PREFERENCES)

temp_output is empty.

Now, I want to transfer the appropriate fields from the other three tables into temp_output. likes_and_music has multiple instances of the same ID's, paired with varying NAMEs and PAGEs, so I'd have to put them in an array.

My projected output is something like the following:

```
0001 msisdn1 male 21 1 2 92 0 College [Jeep, soccer, PC games, etc...]
```

And here's my query so far:

```
Select a.ID, a.MSISDN, a.GENDER, a.AGE, a.DAY, a.MONTH, a.YEAR, a.RELATIONSHIPSTATUS, b.EDUCATION, COLLECT_SET(c.NAME) FROM temp_basic_info a JOIN temp_education b ON (a.ID = b.ID) JOIN likes_and_music c ON (c.ID = b.ID) GROUP BY a.ID, a.MSISDN, a.GENDER, a.AGE, a.DAY, a.MONTH, a.YEAR, a.RELATIONSHIPSTATUS, b.EDUCATION, c.name limit 10;
```

But the latter returns the following error:

**FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10002]: Line 1:311 Invalid column reference 'EDUCATION'**

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you check by adding records without likes_and_music table records?

Answer (score 0):

```
temp_education (ID, NAME)
```

I don't see the column `b.education` for table `temp_education b`

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was a typo. Was supposed to be (ID, EDUCATION)